# Is there a way to get submodule information from a specific DiffEntry or RevCommit?

Tags: jgit

I'm trying to record information about a repository using JGit. Is there a way I can find a submodule's URL and other info from a specific commit in the parent repository?

I've tried to walk through the repo using a SubmoduleWalk, but since the final version of the Repository may not contain the submodule (if it was deleted later), it doesn't seem to find the submodule.

Comment: This seems more like a general Git question. Have you tried to get this information with C-Git? Perhaps, you may want to generalize the question and tag it with `git`.

Comment: This is part of a larger project that is pretty dependent on jgit, so it would be difficult to switch over to any other git library. All I'm really looking for is a way to emulate the `--submodule` flag for `git diff` in jgit.